# Как избавиться от ошибки offer в schema.org?

Tags: seo, веб-программирование, поисковые-системы, продвижение

Помогите решить вопрос. Есть [лендинг](http://fleur-parfum.com/), на нем просто предоставляется информация о духах, без цен.

Пробую внедрить микроразметку schema.org с типом позиций Product. В гугле ошибок нет, в яндексе: ОШИБКА: Не выполнено обязательное условие для продуктовых сниппетов: поле offers отсутствует или пусто.

Я понимаю, что яндекс просит указать цену и при ее добавлении ошибка пропадает, но цена на сайте не предусмотрена.

Подскажите, как правильно указать разметку, что бы пройти проверку и в яндексе тоже?

Что еще можно добавить в мою микроразметку?

Проверяю через:

https://webmaster.yandex.ua/microtest.xml

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Answer (score 2):

[*Разметка структурированными данными*](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=http%3A%2F%2Ffleur-parfum.com%2F) на вашей [*главной странице*](http://fleur-parfum.com/) имеет высокий риск получить санкции Гугл. Категория Продукт применяется только для разметки одного конкретного продукта. [*Инфо Гугл*](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products). В данном случае эта страница является каталогом. Возможно вы можете размечать эту страницу как [**DataCatalog**](https://schema.org/DataCatalog) или же как [**BreadcrumbList**](https://schema.org/BreadcrumbList). В случае разметки одного конкретного продукта как [**Product**](https://schema.org/Product), вы можете применять элемент-расширение offers и далее переходить к разметке [**Offer**](https://schema.org/Offer). Для создания вложенности, вы можете применить разметку [**WebPage**](https://schema.org/WebPage) для отдельных страниц или [**WebSite**](https://schema.org/WebSite) для главной страницы и далее через элемент-расширение mainEntity переходить к разметке Product или DataCatalog. В этом случая последние разметки будут являться составляющей частью от разметки **Веб Страницы/Веб Сайта**.  Это поможет поисковикам понять структуру вашего сайта.